# will soon receive or will receive soon

Tags: word-order, sentence-patterns, adverb-position

I was wondering if there is a specific preference for the `soon` position in the following line:

> You will receive a message with the activation link soon.

Or if it is better/more common to use:

> You will soon receive a message with the activation link.

Is it merely preference or does it have other implications? At first sight I don't really see a form of intonation here that might make the sentence give a different meaning.

My primary language is Dutch, so I might make some mistakes in this field :)

In Dutch we would say:

> Je ontvangt zo spoedig mogelijk je activeringslink per email.

But can also say:

> Je ontvangt je activeringslink zo spoedig mogelijk per email.

Which in both cases `zo spoedig mogelijk` refers to the same principle as the `soon` in the English form. `zo spoedig mogelijk` means `as soon as possible`, whereas `binnenkort` might better refer to `soon` as `in a bit`.

Comment: Look here first: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverb-position ; https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=adverb+position  Try also: https://www.google.com/search?&q=adverb+position+english+grammar&oq=adverb+position+english+grammar Good Luck.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: "Where should the adverb “soon” be positioned?" https://english.stackexchange.com/q/282414/14666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of looking at the problem is in terms of another idea of language in addition to the old ‘*subject - verb - [object]*’.  This is the more semantic distinction into ‘*subject (=topic) - predicate*’.  It divides the sentence into ‘*what I am talking about*’ (subject/topic) and ‘*what I am saying about it*.  This allows us to understand not just the grammar and truth conditions if a sentence, but its intended significance.  This can be done by the manner in which the statement is phrased.

> I love you.
>   is very different from 
>   It’s you I love.

The same can be done by varying the order of the words.  The extent to which this is possible depends on the language and its syntax an accidence.  So in Latin, because it is highly inflected.  you can move subjects and objects around with relative freedom.  In English the lack of inflection reduces the scope, but **adverbs you can move**.  Wow!  I was able to move the object out of its normal position so that it is more clearly the subject (in the sense of topic) of the sentence.

That is what is happening with ‘soon’ in your passage.

A useful way of thinking about it is as if it were the answer to a hypothetical question (unasked)

> You will soon receive a message with the activation link.

This would answer a question like ‘What happens next/now?’. The Topic is what happens next.

> You will receive a message with the activation link **soon**.

This is more suited to the question ‘When will I get the activation link?’.  The topic is not the event so much as its timing.

In this context, therefore, the difference is marginal.  Do you think the user is wondering what happens next, or is wondering about whether there will be a long wait?  Probably neither, since it is the standard procedure.  So stick to the former!

Comment: Thank you Tuffy, this was really clear and good to understand :)

Comment: I was just wondering about a rare quirk in Dutch. If you say for example "I'd like that muffin also". That "also" in the end is sometimes said in Dutch too as a dangling word, but is incorrect there, but it isn't in English right? Maybe I'm wrong tho :)

Comment: @User2910293 Right!

Comment: @User2910293 I am having second thoughts about my ‘right’:  sorry.  The final ‘also’ in English is, I think, mainly conversational.  If I were making a speech, or a letter in which I wanted to stress the addition, I think I would say ‘... as well’.  But don’t trust me on what is pure intuition !

Answer (score 1):

"Is it merely preference or does it have other implications?"

Yes, it does have semantic significance as to where the adverbial appears in a sentence.

The adverb may be placed before the related verb:

> You will **soon** receive a message with the activation link.

It may appear after the object/complement:

> You will receive a message with the activation link **soon**.

Or to emphasise the adverbial itself, at the front:

> **Soon**, you will receive a message with the activation link.